# Surface particles are engulfed when a noise texture, vector displacement is applied. How to fix?

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image]

As you can see, i am making a donut with sprinkles but after i applied a vector displacement using noise texture to the icing, the sprinkles are engulfed. Is there any way to fix this by moving the sprinkles to the surface of the icing after the displacement or any other way? Am quite new to blender so sorry if this is a dumb question or if I've got anything wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using a Displace modifier, or displacement in the shader.  If you're using a modifier make sure it is before the Particle system in the displacement stack.

Comment: I think there is an addon to solve this (I don't know the name), but to avoid this issue with material nodes you would have to bake the displacement to an image texture and use that image in a Displacement modifier.  Then do as Marty Fouts has advised.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but where can i find the displacement stack?

Comment: That's a typo. Marty Fouts means the *modifier* stack. The modifiers are used in top-down order. A *Displacement* modifier must go first, then a *Particle System* modifier should follow. This order allows the particles to use the modified mesh. Else they use the unmodified mesh which gets moved around after the particles have been placed.

Comment: I have done this but i still get the same issue, although it does say something about having the same subdivision surface on the render and viewport which I don't have. Do you think this could be it?

Comment: Yes, it could be. The *Subdivision Surface* levels should be equal else the result can look different in the viewport and in the final render. For better performance, you can lower the levels for the viewport. But keep in mind it can mess up particles. Is the screenshot above the final render (F12)?